# CSS/JQuery selectors: Is there anyway to select classes in classes?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Let's suppose that we have the following markup:

```
<div class="t-shirt black blue">Example</div>
<div class="t-shirt white blue">Example</div>
<div class="sweater black blue">Example</div>
<div class="sweater black red">Example</div>
<div class="sweater white red">Example</div>
<div class="hat black blue">Example</div>
<div class="hat black red">Example</div>
<div class="hat white red">Example</div>
```

Is there anyway to select `t-shirt` OR `sweater` that are black AND blue with one selector? I mean, without using comma separated selectors.

For example, I DON'T want to do the following:

```
var wanted = $('.t-shirt.black.blue, .sweater.black.blue');
```

Is there anyway to do something similar to the following? (I know it doesn't work):

```
var wanted = $('(.t-shirt, .sweater).black.blue');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you would need a comma to do the or.

Comment: You sure? Any better alternative you would suggest?

Comment: Why no coma-separated selectors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. Neither in jQuery nor CSS.

Even if there were a functional pseudo-class for grouping parts of selectors (such as the upcoming [`:matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#matches) in Selectors 4), you would still need to supply a comma-separated list of those classes anyway:

```
:matches(.t-shirt, .sweater).black.blue
```

Needless to say, the above selector doesn't work in any browser (yet). You *could* [implement it yourself as a Sizzle extension](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation) if you really wanted to, but I honestly wouldn't bother.

Comment: There are days, here, on Stack Overflow, when I look at your answers and think I should just give you *all* my up-votes. ...automatically. +1 (needless to say!) :)

Comment: @David Thomas: What am I, the Jon Skeet of [css]? ;)

Comment: Basically: yes, actually. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that:

```
var wanted = $('.black.blue').filter('.t-shirt, .sweater');
```

But

```
var wanted = $('.t-shirt.black.blue, .sweater.black.blue');
```

might be more effective anyway (I have not tested that though)

Comment: I will use `.filter()`. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

If the only goal is not using the comma, you could do this:

```
var blackblue = $(".black.blue"),
    tshirts = blackblue.filter(".t-shirt"),
    sweaters = blackblue.filter(".sweater"),
    both = tshirts.add(sweaters);
```

however i don't see how it is any better, unless it allows you to organize better.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectionLevel1 = $(".t-shirt, .sweater").andSelf();
var finalSelection = $(".black", selectionLevel1);
```